# Changing Content-Type Header of static files in IIS 6 with out access to IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-6

I'm trying to change the content type of static files severed by IIS6 on a shared host where I don't have access to IIS I tried

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
   <remove fileExtension=".manifest" />
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".manifest" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

In my web.config but that appears to only work with IIS7
In case there is any doubt after that sample I am trying to change all static files served with the extension .manifest to have the mimeType text/cache-manifest

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Comment: @SLaks :( Meep! I did not want to write a IHttpHandler for this. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy changing the MIME types for the entire web server AND you can run ASP.NET code then this snippet will add the MIME types for you in IIS 6 (the code is from http://forums.silverlight.net/p/138545/449294.aspx):

```
try
{
    string ext = ".xap";
    string mime = "application/x-silverlight-app";

    using (DirectoryEntry mimeMap = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/MimeMap"))
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (MimeMap m in mimeMap.Properties["MimeMap"])
        {
            if (m.Extension == ext)
            {
                // found existing, update
                m.MimeType = mime;
                found = true;
            }
        }

        // not found, create new
        if (!found)
        {
            mimeMap.Properties["MimeMap"].Add(new MimeMapClass { Extension = ext, MimeType = mime });
        }

        // commit changes
        mimeMap.CommitChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Log exception to event viewer
    // Show message stating to configure mime type manually
}
```

I found out pretty quickly that you can only add one MIME type at a time, if you want add more than that you will have to instantiate a new directory server instance for every MIME type you add..

Hope that helps...